Updating Pivot with new date using VBA
I am trying to build a macro which will refresh a pivot with a new date, based on what date is written in a given cell.
For instance if in cell A5 I have 25th Nov, I want the pivot to refresh and present results only for 25th Nov, if I change the date, I would like the macro to use the updated date.
Basically I need to build a macro that will refresh the date field, based on the date input in A5 as on the below image
enter image description here
As of now I managed to create a macro that refreshes the pivot with a new date, but I am not sure how to change the manually inputted dates to the dates which would be in a cell.
Sub Refresh_new_date()
'
' Refresh_new_date Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
        .PivotItems("11/17/2024").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("11/18/2024").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub


You need to handle the Worksheet_Change event:
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
        .PivotItems([A5]).Visible = True
        .PivotItems("11/18/2024").Visible = False
    End With
  End If
End Sub


Of cause, you need to automate this line too:
        .PivotItems("11/18/2024").Visible = False


How is it going?
